# How to add a side-navigation in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I want to add a side navigation like this to my side:

> https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

There should be a menu button and a sidenav opens:

[image]

But i cant find this method in `polymer`. The only possibility is the `paper-drawer-panel` but this is opend all the time...

My working paper-drawer-panel example: https://www.sese7.de/polymer/

Does anybody has an idea how to do this with polymer or maybe with https://customelements.io/

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `forceNarrow` attribute to true.

Below is the documentation from the paper-drawer-panel api docs: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel

> forceNarrow
>
> Boolean
>
> default: false
>
> If true, ignore responsiveWidth setting and force the narrow layout.

Answer (score 0):

Paper-drawer-panel has a `closeDrawer()`-method.

A short example here:

```
var drawerPanel = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#paperDrawerPanel');

if (drawerPanel.narrow) {
    drawerPanel.closeDrawer();
}
```

The example is from "Polymer Starter Kit".